# scala Duration: "This class is not meant as a general purpose representation of time, it is optimized for the needs of scala.concurrent."

Tags: scala, time, concurrency, duration, java-8

I was reading the [scala doc for the `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration` class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.duration.Duration), and I just discovered that it starts with:

> This class is not meant as a general purpose representation of time, it is optimized for the needs of scala.concurrent.

Why are the implications of this statement? What's a better alternative?

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'm partially responsible for this.

The general issue here is that time system are hard. Really, really, really hard.

The Akka developers who worked on standardizing Futures needed a construct to describe the length between two “anonymous” points in time to implement their functionality. `Duration` was built to solve this specific requirement.

My concern was that people might start using this time-related class for things it wasn't designed for bringing us into a troublesome situation comparable to `java.util.Date`/`java.util.Calendar` (not quite because `Duration` actually works for its use-case) where tons of people would misuse it as some kind of  `scala.time` which it was never intended to be.

That's why it has this note and is packaged into `scala.concurrent.duration` instead of e. g. `scala.time`.

I look forward to the `java.time` package shipping with Java 8. It might be possible to standardize on that in the future which would improve interoperability a bit and would have the additional benefit of being designed for a much broader use-case. (It will probably take a long time until Scala uses Java 8 as a baseline, though...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am still wondering if there are concrete examples of what you should *not* do with Duration?

Answer (score 3):

Time can be represented in various ways depending on your needs. I personally have used:

1. `Long` — a lot of tools take it directly
2. **Updated**: `java.time.*` thanks to @Vladimir Matveev

   The package is designed by the author of Joda Time (Stephen Colebourne). [He says](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) it is designed better.
3. [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
4. <s>`java.util.Date`</s>
5. Separate hierarchy of classes:

   ```
   trait Time
   case class ExactTime(timeMs:Long) extends Time
   case object Now extends Time
   case object ASAP extends Time
   case class RelativeTime(origin:Time, deltaMs:Long) extends Time
   ```
6. Ordered time representation:

   ```
   case class History[T](events:List[T])
   ```
7. Model time. Once I had a global object `Timer` with `var currentTime:Long`:

   ```
   object Timer {
     private var currentTimeValue:Long
     def currentTimeMs = currentTimeValue
     def currentTimeMs_=(newTime:Long) { ... some checks and notifications}
     def pseudoRandom:Double = ...
   }
   ```

   And everywhere in the program I called `Timer.currentTimeMs` to get the time. It allows to write deterministic tests with controlled time shift. (Beware of global variable! Now I prefer to use separate instances of `Timer` to avoid concurrency issues.)

Comment: I'd put Joda Time to the first position in the list. And it's not `java.util.Date` which is usable in Java 8, it's `java.time.*` packages.

Comment: There is also Twitter util Time, but I am still wondering when you should use one or the other.